# On Ruby on Rails 2.3.5, render_to_string is not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.5, but when I use (in HAML)

```
- s = render_to_string :text => "hello"
```

or render a partial, it says `render_to_string` is not a defined method?  Clearly it is in the API:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465

Right now I am using this instead:

```
- s = render :text => "hello"
```

since it is `-` in front, the output is not sent to the webpage output, but `render` also returns a string for `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the documentation for `ActionController`. The `render` you are actually calling is in `ActionView::TemplateHandler`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/TemplateHandler.html#M002322

Comment: so it is almost no documentation at all?  In the existing code, I can call render in the View almost the same as in Controller.

Comment: Correct, the docs are pretty bad, and the two versions of render are similar but not identical.